# Set a combox to display and item based on DisplayMember

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I have a combo box set-up in the following way :

```
With Me.cboEmps
        .DataSource = myDSemp.Tables(0) 'results of an SQL statement
        .DisplayMember = "employee" 'employee name
        .ValueMember = "employee_id"
End With
```

I would like to set the selected item in the combo box using the "employee" display member. I need to refer to the ValueMember for the next part of a function and so I cannot just display the correct text, I need to have the correct item selected.

I tried various methods including:

```
index = cboEmps.Items.IndexOf(name)
cboEmps.SelectedIndex = index
```

but index always comes back as -1.

```
cboEmps.SelectedText = name
```

This ends up with the combo box displaying a string of names added each one after another as I trigger the event.

I want to try and avoid doing some timely loop which goes through each item in the combo box, compares the display member etc.

Kind regards

Matt

Answer (score 0):

You use the original datasource to search for your employee name, once you got it then it is easy to get its employeeid and set the SelectedValue property

```
Dim name = "EmpName"
Dim rows = myDSemp.Tables(0).Select("employee='" & name & "'")
If rows.Count > 0 Then
   cboEmps.SelectedValue = Convert.ToInt32(rows(0)("employee_id"))
End If
```

Comment: Unfortunately the combo box data source is set on the form load and the event that triggers needing to change the selected item is from a click event on a datagrid. I don't have access to the datasource at the point when I want to run this code.

Comment: The DataSource of the combobox contains the data that you need to look at. It is a DataView, You just need to _dim view  = DirectCast(cbo.DataSource, System.Data.DefaultView)_ followed by _dim table = view.Table_

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
cboEmps.Text = name
```

it should (assuming DropDownStyle = DropDownList) set the `SelectedItem` properly.

You could also do something similar to Steve's answer by accessing the combobox datasource:

```
Dim tmpCboEmps As DataTable = cboEmps.DataSource

' find employee by name from clicked item
' set cboEmps.SelectedItem = employee
```